# conways game of life not working properly

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, conways-game-of-life, gridworld

I am having trouble with my conway's game of life program(If you are not familiar with it here is a link that explains it and towards the top are the rules. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Game_of_Life).  I am using gridworld and when I run the code it produces the grid and changes its state.  It all looks as if it were working properly.  However the cells that are supposed to die/come alive do not.  Instead a seemingly random assortment of cells change their state.  I cannot figure out the problem.  I have checked to make sure the right number of neighbors is found, the if statements are working properly, and if I am comparing the correct things.  All of these seem to work, yet I see an unexpected result.  Please help me fix this.  Thanks in advance.
PS. Please Ignore the commented out code.  They are tests/failed attempts to make it work.
Here is my code:

```
import info.gridworld.actor.Actor;
import info.gridworld.actor.ActorWorld;
import info.gridworld.actor.Rock;
import info.gridworld.grid.Grid;
import info.gridworld.grid.BoundedGrid;
import info.gridworld.grid.Location;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Game of Life starter code. Demonstrates how to create and populate the game using the GridWorld framework.
 * Also demonstrates how to provide accessor methods to make the class testable by unit tests.
 * 
 * @author @
 * @version 14 Nov 2014
 */
public class GameOfLife
{


  // the world comprised of the grid that displays the graphics for the game
private static ActorWorld world;

// the game board will have 10 rows and 10 columns
private final int ROWS = 10;
private final int COLS = 10;

// constants for the location of the three cells initially alive
private final int X1 = 0, Y1 = 0;
private final int X2 = 0, Y2 = 4;
private final int X3 = 0, Y3 = 5;
private final int X4 = 0, Y4 = 9;
private final int X5 = 1, Y5 = 0;
private final int X6 = 1, Y6 = 5;
private final int X7 = 1, Y7 = 9;
private final int X8 = 2, Y8 = 0;
private final int X9 = 2, Y9 = 9;
private final int X10 = 4, Y10 = 0;
private final int X11 = 4, Y11 = 1;
private final int X12 = 4, Y12 = 4;
private final int X13 = 4, Y13 = 5;
private final int X14 = 4, Y14 = 9;
private final int X15 = 5, Y15 = 0;
private final int X16 = 5, Y16 = 4;
private final int X17 = 5, Y17 = 5;
private final int X18 = 5, Y18 = 8;
private final int X19 = 5, Y19 = 9;
private final int X20 = 7, Y20 = 0;
private final int X21 = 7, Y21 = 9;
private final int X22 = 8, Y22 = 0;
private final int X23 = 8, Y23 = 4;
private final int X24 = 8, Y24 = 9;
private final int X25 = 9, Y25 = 0;
private final int X26 = 9, Y26 = 4;
private final int X27 = 9, Y27 = 5;
private final int X28 = 9, Y28 = 9;

/**
 * Default constructor for objects of class GameOfLife
 * 
 * @post    the game will be initialized and populated with the initial state of cells
 * 
 */
public GameOfLife()
{
    // create the grid, of the specified size, that contains Actors

    BoundedGrid<Actor> grid = new BoundedGrid<Actor>(ROWS, COLS);

    // create a world based on the grid
    world = new ActorWorld(grid);

    // populate the game
    populateGame();

    // display the newly constructed and populated world
    world.show();

}

/**
 * Creates the actors and inserts them into their initial starting positions in the grid
 *
 * @pre     the grid has been created
 * @post    all actors that comprise the initial state of the game have been added to the grid
 * 
 */
public void populateGame()
{
    // the grid of Actors that maintains the state of the game
    //  (alive cells contains actors; dead cells do not)
    Grid<Actor> grid = world.getGrid();

    // create and add rocks (a type of Actor) to the three intial locations
    Rock rock1 = new Rock();
    Location loc1 = new Location(X1, Y1);
    grid.put(loc1, rock1);

    Rock rock2 = new Rock();
    Location loc2 = new Location(X2, Y2);
    grid.put(loc2, rock2);

    Rock rock3 = new Rock();
    Location loc3 = new Location(X3, Y3);
    grid.put(loc3, rock3);

    Rock rock4 = new Rock();
    Location loc4 = new Location(X4, Y4);
    grid.put(loc4, rock4);

    Rock rock5 = new Rock();
    Location loc5 = new Location(X5, Y5);
    grid.put(loc5, rock5);

    Rock rock6 = new Rock();
    Location loc6 = new Location(X6, Y6);
    grid.put(loc6, rock6);

    Rock rock7 = new Rock();
    Location loc7 = new Location(X7, Y7);
    grid.put(loc7, rock7);

    Rock rock8 = new Rock();
    Location loc8 = new Location(X8, Y8);
    grid.put(loc8, rock8);

    Rock rock9 = new Rock();
    Location loc9 = new Location(X9, Y9);
    grid.put(loc9, rock9);

    Rock rock10 = new Rock();
    Location loc10 = new Location(X10, Y10);
    grid.put(loc10, rock10);

    Rock rock11 = new Rock();
    Location loc11 = new Location(X11, Y11);
    grid.put(loc11, rock11);

    Rock rock12 = new Rock();
    Location loc12 = new Location(X12, Y12);
    grid.put(loc12, rock12);

    Rock rock13 = new Rock();
    Location loc13 = new Location(X13, Y13);
    grid.put(loc13, rock13);

    Rock rock14 = new Rock();
    Location loc14 = new Location(X14, Y14);
    grid.put(loc14, rock14);

    Rock rock15 = new Rock();
    Location loc15 = new Location(X15, Y15);
    grid.put(loc15, rock15);

    Rock rock16 = new Rock();
    Location loc16 = new Location(X16, Y16);
    grid.put(loc16, rock16);

    Rock rock17 = new Rock();
    Location loc17 = new Location(X17, Y17);
    grid.put(loc17, rock17);

    Rock rock18 = new Rock();
    Location loc18 = new Location(X18, Y18);
    grid.put(loc18, rock18);

    Rock rock19 = new Rock();
    Location loc19 = new Location(X19, Y19);
    grid.put(loc19, rock19);

    Rock rock20 = new Rock();
    Location loc20 = new Location(X20, Y20);
    grid.put(loc20, rock20);

    Rock rock21 = new Rock();
    Location loc21 = new Location(X21, Y21);
    grid.put(loc21, rock21);

    Rock rock22 = new Rock();
    Location loc22 = new Location(X22, Y22);
    grid.put(loc22, rock22);

    Rock rock23 = new Rock();
    Location loc23 = new Location(X23, Y23);
    grid.put(loc23, rock23);

    Rock rock24 = new Rock();
    Location loc24 = new Location(X24, Y24);
    grid.put(loc24, rock24);

    Rock rock25 = new Rock();
    Location loc25 = new Location(X25, Y25);
    grid.put(loc25, rock25);

    Rock rock26 = new Rock();
    Location loc26 = new Location(X26, Y26);
    grid.put(loc26, rock26);

    Rock rock27 = new Rock();
    Location loc27 = new Location(X27, Y27);
    grid.put(loc27, rock27);

    Rock rock28 = new Rock();
    Location loc28 = new Location(X28, Y28);
    grid.put(loc28, rock28);
    world.show();
    //Grid<Actor> grid2 = world.getGrid();
   // Location test = new Location(0, 0);
   // System.out.println(grid2.getOccupiedAdjacentLocations(test).size());
   // if (grid2.getOccupiedAdjacentLocations(test).size()<2)
   // {System.out.print("dfghjkl");}
}

/**
 * Generates the next generation based on the rules of the Game of Life and updates the grid
 * associated with the world
 *
 * @pre     the game has been initialized
 * @post    the world has been populated with a new grid containing the next generation
 * 
 */
public void createNextGeneration()
{
    /** You will need to read the documentation for the World, Grid, and Location classes
     *      in order to implement the Game of Life algorithm and leverage the GridWorld framework.
     */

    // create the grid, of the specified size, that contains Actors
    Grid<Actor> grid = world.getGrid();
    BoundedGrid<Actor> newGrid= new BoundedGrid<Actor>(10,10);
    Rock rock = new Rock();
    // insert magic here...
    //ArrayList<Location> put = new ArrayList<Location>();
    //ArrayList<Location> remove = new ArrayList<Location>();

    for (int row = 0; row<=9; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col<=9; col++)
        {
            //int index = row+col;
            Location loc = new Location(row, col);
            //Location test = new Location(0, 0);
            //System.out.println(loc);
            //System.out.println(grid.getOccupiedAdjacentLocations(test));
            if (getActor(row, col) != null)
            {
                if (grid.getOccupiedAdjacentLocations(loc).size()<2 || grid.getOccupiedAdjacentLocations(loc).size()>3)
                {
                   //remove.add(new Location(row, col));
                   //remove[index] =  new Location(row, col);
                   grid.remove(loc);
                   // System.out.println(loc);
                }
                else if(grid.getOccupiedAdjacentLocations(loc).size()==2 ||
                        grid.getOccupiedAdjacentLocations(loc).size()==3)
                {
                    //remove.add(new Location(row, col));
                    //remove[index] = new Location(row, col);
                    grid.put(loc, rock);
                }           
            }
            else
            {
                if (grid.getOccupiedAdjacentLocations(loc).size()==3)
                   {
                       // put.add(new Location(row, col));
                        //put[index] = new Location(row, col);
                        grid.put(loc, rock);
                    }
                }            
        }

    }

    /*System.out.println(putLoc);
    for (int i = 1; i<=put.size() && i<=remove.size(); i++)
    {
        Location[] putLoc = put.toArray(new Location[put.size()]);
        Location[] removeLoc = put.toArray(new Location[remove.size()]);
        if (i<=put.size())
        {
             grid.put(putLoc[i], rock);                
         }
        if (i<=remove.size())
        {
             grid.remove(removeLoc[i]);
         }
    }*/
}

/**
 * Returns the actor at the specified row and column. Intended to be used for unit testing.
 *
 * @param   row the row (zero-based index) of the actor to return
 * @param   col the column (zero-based index) of the actor to return
 * @pre     the grid has been created
 * @return  the actor at the specified row and column
 */
public Actor getActor(int row, int col)
{
    Location loc = new Location(row, col);
    Actor actor = world.getGrid().get(loc);
    return actor;
}

/**
 * Returns the number of rows in the game board
 *
 * @return    the number of rows in the game board
 */
public int getNumRows()
{
    return ROWS;
}

/**
 * Returns the number of columns in the game board
 *
 * @return    the number of columns in the game board
 */
public int getNumCols()
{
    return COLS;
}


/**
 * Creates an instance of this class. Provides convenient execution.
 *
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
    throws InterruptedException
{
    GameOfLife game = new GameOfLife();

    for (int i = 0; i<=19; i++)
    {
       Thread.sleep(200);
       game.createNextGeneration();
       world.show();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you remove an a rock from the grid, it is removed instantly, so the nearby locations that have yet to be checked will not see that object as being present. A similar problem exists for adding rocks... they appear instantly so future checks on the adjacent locations will return unexpected results.

The solution is to store the changes that need to be made so that they are delayed until the entire grid is checked.